# Can we call a function in angular using scope array?

Tags: angularjs

I have a small doubt in angular can we call a function like this?

```
$scope.params = 'callMe';
    $scope.myFunction($scope.params);
    $scope.myFunction = function(name) {
        $scope[name]();
    }
    $scope.callMe = function() {
        console.log("yehh..It's possible.);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible because `$scope[name]()` will render to `$scope.callMe()`.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.params = 'callMe';

    $scope.callMe = function() {
        console.log("yehh..It's possible.");
    }
    $scope.myFunction = function(name) {
        $scope[name]();
    }
    $scope.myFunction($scope.params);

}
```

**Working Fiddle** :http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11799/

Comment: Thanks For this. I understood

Comment: Glad to know it was of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can, Javascript supports a ["Bracket notation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation), but I'd suggest checking if function with given name exists in scope beforehand:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(name) {
    if(typeof $scope[name] === 'function') {
        $scope[name]();
    }
}
```